# How to get a list of articles filtered by tag using django-taggit?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-taggit

I want to list articles by tag to have the title of the tag in the title and the titles of the articles in the list.
My view.py looks like this:

```
from taggit.models import TaggedItem

class ArticlesByTagsList(ListView):

    template_name = 'articles/articles_by_tags.html'
    context_object_name = 'articles_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return TaggedItem.objects.filter(tag=self.kwargs['tag'])

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['tags_list'] = Tag.objects.all()
        return context
```

My articles_by_tags.html template looks like this:

```
{% block content %}

    <h1>Список публикаций {{ articles_list.item }}</h1>

    {% for item in articles_list %}
        <h2>{{ item }}</h2>
    {% endfor %}


{% endblock %}
```

I end up with the following output:[ArticlesByTagsList.as_view() result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BVEN.jpg)

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I solved the problem with displaying the list of articles by changing get_queryset:
`def get_queryset(self):
return Article.objects.filter(tags__name=self.kwargs['tag'])`
But I still can't get the name of the tag in the title of the page by which the list is filtered.

Comment: I added this code to the get_context_data:
`context['current_tag'] = Tag.objects.get(name=self.kwargs['tag'])`
And it worked!